# npm doesn't work, get always this error -> Error: Cannot find module 'are-we-there-yet'

Tags: node.js, macos, installation, npm

i tried to install grunt on a mac with Yosemite. node is already installed in the newest version. if i type "node -v" in the terminal i get the line v0.12.5. thats good. but when i want to install something with npm i get only a error...

i tried "sudo npm install -g grunt-cli", "sudo npm install npm -g" and also with  "npm -v" i get always this error...

```
Error: Cannot find module 'are-we-there-yet'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
at require (module.js:384:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.22/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npmlog/log.js:2:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
```

someone knows what's the problem or better a solution?

Comment: It says it can't find the module 'are-we-there-yet'. What is it?

Comment: i dont know. i have nothing new installed or anything, just updated node 

`sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable`

and then i tried to install grunt

Comment: It says you're trying to install a module called 'are-we-there-yet'. Did you do `npm install are-we-there-yet` by any chance?

Comment: no i dont try to install a module with the name "are-we-there-yet". i get this error if i try to install grunt or get the version of npm with
`sudo npm install -g grunt-cli` or `npm -v`

Answer (score 102, accepted):

You have broken `npm` by removing some of its dependencies.

`are-we-there-yet` is a dependency of `npmlog` which is a dependency of `npm` itself, and you somehow deleted it. The usual simple solution for such cases is reinstalling a package, but that doesn't work if `npm` cannot operate. Fortunately, `npm` tarball comes prebundled with dependencies and hence [installing `npm` from scratch](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-node#installing-npm-manually) is as simple as unpacking a tarball.

1) Go to the global `node_modules` directory (what would `npm root -g` print if you could run it):

```
$ cd /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

2) Remove the broken `npm` directory or move it somewhere else (note that you might need to elevate permissions for this and the following steps):

```
$ mv npm /tmp
```

3) Download and unpack fresh `npm` from the registry (substitute version you want to install, e.g. `3.10.8`):

```
$ curl -L registry.npmjs.com/npm/-/npm-{VERSION}.tgz | tar xz --transform="s:^package:npm:"
```

You can automate some of that with this install script:

```
$ curl -L https://www.npmjs.com/install.sh | sh
```

At this point `npm` should work again.

Comment: thank you for your answer, i will try it in the evening ;)

Comment: Was running into this issue with fresh installs on ubuntu 14.04, this fixed it for me. (adjusting for version #)

Comment: I dont have the `Cellar` directory

Comment: ...however `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` seemed to do the trick

Comment: @Horse Yeah, that was specific to OP's case (see the stack trace in the question). Just changed it.

Comment: It isn't necessarily true that the user broke their own system. I hit this same problem bringing up a fresh Vagrant VM. See https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9668

Comment: You can find a more comprehensive way to remove node here, which was necessary for me:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/11178106/1332513

Comment: I've had problems with 4). Solved by checking what is currently the latest npm version and modifying the tarball name accordingly in the curl command.

Comment: @Muzietto Updated `npm` version in the post. Thanks!

Comment: A thank you from the future. *If you are following this advice from the future* lol

Comment: On macOS, you need to install `gnu-tar`: `brew install gnu-tar` and then use `gtar` instead of `tar`.

Answer (score 13):

Go to the global node_modules directory (npm root -g if you don't know)

```
$ cd /usr/local/lib/node_modules

curl -L https://www.npmjs.com/install.sh | sh
```

Answer (score 12):

Even i had same issue, Easiest way to solve below steps worked for me.

1. uninstall Nodejs.
2. Go to `C:/Users/<user_name>/AppData/Roaming.`
3. Delete `npm` directory.
4. Reinstall `Nodejs` (latest *v6.11.3*,includes *npm 3.10.10*).
5. Done Now try to check (`npm -v`) will be working fine.

Answer (score 7):

What eush77 said, but if you're on Windows:

download the latest package from 
https://nodejs.org/download/release/npm/

unpack, and replace the "npm" directory in the nodejs node-modules directory 
(by default C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules)

Answer (score 7):

I have been trying feverishly to get to the latest version of node and npm on my centos 7 machine.

Unfortunately, I have been plagued with this error for near a week now. And I have finally found a solution that works.

If your npm is currently broken, It is easiest just to install a working version again.

I installed from code. Assuming git is installed, the following commands will accomplish that goal

```
cd ~
git clone https://github.com/nodejs/node.git nodejs_code
cd nodejs_code
./configure
make
make install
```

After you have installed a fresh copy of npm and node, which by the way is not the stable version (Instead its bleeding edge right from source).

Installed version of node at time of writing this was 5.0.0-pre which is too new for me, and npm was version 2.14.4 which is too old for me.

To get to the latest version on node, I will install the 'n' package using npm. Using n, I will install the latest version of node.

```
npm install -g n
n stable
```

In the case of the root user, (which I use to install global packages) I needed to add the following line to my `~/.bashrc` file, which will allow the root user to access the commands in /usr/local/bin commands. (You may not need this step)

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

At this point my version of node is 4.0.0 which is the latest stable version of node.

now to update npm, which was the most annoying thing ever.

Updating directly to the newest version always resulted in "are-we-there-yet" which I could only surmise as "NO, and Quit Asking or I will turn this node around"

Instead I have found that installing through version 3.3.3 first would solve this problem.

```
npm install -g npm@3.3.3
```

now version 3.3.3 is installed and works without the "are-we-there-yet" error.

Thank goodness. Keep your arms inside and you seatbelts fastened kids, because we are almost there.....

```
npm install -g npm
```

and with that final command, I was able to use the latest version of npm, with the latest stable version of node. Which at the time of writing this is 3.3.5

From here on out, my commands are as follows.

```
n stable
npm install -g npm
```

each time I run these from here on out, I am granted undisturbed npm trips without the kids complaining in the back.

### Note

As I am moderating a number of servers, none of which come with node by default, I find myself having to perform this task over and over..

Therefore I have taken it upon myself to turn these instructions into a script.

Enjoy:

importnode.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ~
git clone https://github.com/nodejs/node.git nodejs_code
cd nodejs_code
git reset --hard
git pull origin master
./configure
make
make install

if [[ `cat ~/.bashrc |grep -E "PATH.*/usr/local/bin:.*"` ]];
then
    echo "Already Done";
else
    echo "export PATH=/usr/local/bin:\$PATH" >> ~/.bashrc;
    export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH;
fi;

npm install -g n
n stable

npm install -g npm@3.3.3

npm install -g npm
```

The only thing left to do after putting this into nodeimport.sh is to make it executable and execute it.

```
$ chmod +x importnode.sh
$ ./importnode.sh
```

Wait a while, and all is installed.

Comment: Please help me.above solutions are not working for me.

Comment: Did you install a fresh copy of nodejs/npm when you started these directions ?

Comment: This answer was awesome! perfect guide. Been looking for an answer to this problem all night! Big +1 from me!

Comment: yes i have tried apt-get remove nodejs and apt-get remove node and apt-get remove npm.then i started these directions.

Comment: tell you what. Pose your question on stackoverflow.com, put in the attempts you have made, as well as the output from those attempts. Then put a link here and I will take a look. It is difficult to attack a problem on conjecture.

Comment: @TheLazyCoder Thanks it worked for me.actually problem was that the directory of npm was not getting deleted when i deleted directory of npm your solution worked for me.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could also reinstall `node` from `https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/`

Answer (score 1):

I followed the instructions above (what eush77 said) to remove the npm folder in the node_modules folder.  But there remains the broken link resulting in this error message.

**/usr/local/bin/npm: No such file or directory**

so remove the broken link:

`rm /usr/local/bin/npm`

and then make it point to the right place like this:

`sudo ln -s /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js /usr/local/bin/npm`

Answer (score 0):

For me this had to do with installations being corrupted and perhaps ubuntu repositories not being compatible or the most recent. The following resulted in a working npm/node install:

sudo curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs

https://github.com/nodesource/distributions

Answer (score 0):

I got it reset by using the official installer package found: https://nodejs.org/en/

Playing around with n and nvm eventually corrupted the node_modules packages for me by providing packages incompatible with current Node version.

I suspect it'd work for other environments as it couples both Node AND npm install.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to remove my project's `node_modules` folder. I then cleaned the cache just in case and did a fresh `npm i` and it was able to do the node-sass post-install and not error at `are-we-there-yet` missing.

**If moving global `node_modules` doesn't work for you like in the solutions above try:**

1. Remove your project's local `node_modules`

   - In your project's root: `rm -rf node_moduldes`
2. `npm cache clean -f`
3. `npm i`

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem while deploying the project on local server when I was invoking the `yarn dev` command.

After going through all the blogs, articles and stuff I got it working just by simple this 2 commands.

1. `npm list` check at what version it is pointing right now. For me, when I was getting this error. It was pointing to the system.
2. I just used the `nvm use v{VERSION}` e.g. `nvm use v10.5.0` (for me) and it got working. All the errors went away and the project got deployed successfully while invoking the `yarn dev`. Try this before doing anything else. I highly recommend.

Answer (score 0):

### For Windows

I solved the problem without reinstalling by downloading the package [are-we-there-yet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/are-we-there-yet) from Github

https://github.com/npm/are-we-there-yet

(or from the release page a "Source code (zip)": https://github.com/npm/are-we-there-yet/releases)

Unzip the folder, rename it to `are-we-there-yet` and copy it into the following folder:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules
```

You can then install a suitable version with `npm i -g npm@x.x.x` if necessary.