# When running npm I get this error - npm cannot find module 'are-we-there-yet' on Ubuntu 14

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, installation

I've followed the guide over at

[npm doesn't work, get always this error -> Error: Cannot find module 'are-we-there-yet'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31025048/npm-doesnt-work-get-always-this-error-error-cannot-find-module-are-we-there)

However, when I run the

```
cd /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.40/lib/node_modules [adjusted for current version
```

Command it says it doesn't exist... which it doesn't....

In fact there is no local/Cellar command.

node --version returns 0.10.40

every time I run npm i receive this error

```
module.js:340
throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module 'are-we-there-yet'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> 
(/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npmlog/log.js:2:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

I installed nodejs with apt-get.

I wanted to post this as a comment on the original link but need some rep for that.

Comment: Have you tried a reinstall yet? 'sudo apt-get install --reinstall node'

Comment: `cd /usr/local/lib/node_modules` instead :)

Comment: Which repository have you used to install node?

Answer (score 1):

I think its beacause of npm version incompatibility 
I went through following steps

```
$>npm --version
$>1.3.10
$>sudo npm install -g --upgrade npm
$>npm --version
$>2.12.0
```

now everything working fine for me.

More detailed information at http://paste.openstack.org/show/473108/