# Can't deploy my node.js app anymore on ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

An old app at work stoped working on an aws machine. I've been assigned the task, but I'm more of a Rails guy. And this is node.js using an old Sails. I tried a bunch of stuff and now even my npm seem broken. I get this error:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-5-52:~$ npm -v
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:605
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'are-we-there-yet'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:603:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:25)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:659:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npmlog/log.js:2:16)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:734:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:552:3)
```

Comment: Have you tried installing the npm packages? Try running: `npm install`

Comment: same error with npm install

Comment: actually when I first started working this problem,    npm install was starting and I had an error on the way. I tried updating npm and then some more stuff and now it's broken I guess.

Comment: What happens when you run `node -v`? You might need to reinstall npm and/or node

Comment: I got it running following this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31025048/npm-doesnt-work-get-always-this-error-error-cannot-find-module-are-we-the