# Npm -v error: cannot find module 'are-we-there-yet'

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I recently upgraded nodejs from v6.9.2 to V10.16.3. But after the upgrade I am not able to do npm install.

npm -v gives the following error -

Error: cannot find module 'are-we-there-yet'

I have tried uninstalling nodejs and reinstalled it. But still getting the same error.

Any solution would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You have broken `npm` by removing some of its dependencies. `are-we-there-yet` is a dependency of **npmlog** which is a dependency of npm itself, and you somehow deleted it.

So you have to reinstall the node from scratch - https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-node-js-and-npm

Comment: I tried re- installing but still getting the same error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31025048/npm-doesnt-work-get-always-this-error-error-cannot-find-module-are-we-the This is a repeated question. Please check the link that I put in the comment. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Hm, pretty strange error, try to install it globally with `npm i are-we-there-yet -g`

Comment: Have the same problem... installation not possible because npm is broken.